# How to associate entity to multiple entities?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm new to JPA and perhaps I'm thinking about this in the wrong way? I want to create an Attachment entity that will allow me to upload attachments to more than just one entity. At present I've set up a OneToMany relationship inside my Product class...

```
@OneToMany(
    mappedBy="product",
    fetch=FetchType.LAZY,
    cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@IndexedEmbedded
private Set<Attachment> attachment;
```

And inside my Attachments class I've set up the other side to the relationship.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false) 
private Product product;
```

This all works fine but I want to use the same code with my Company entity and any entities that need attachments associated. The problem I've found is that I have to bind the Attachments class to the Product. How do I use the same code in more than one class? I thought about a superclass but found it has to be annotated with @Entity otherwise it won't work. Is this something generics could do? I just don't have enough experience to know how to get this to work.

UPDATE:

After reading Clijsters comments I tried modifying the attachment class without a ManyToOne connection and it worked perfectly but poses another question. I'd ultimately like to have a shared attachment resource library. The idea being to upload a file to a Product and be able to share that attachment with another Product or a Company. 
How would I view all the products or companies that attachment is connected to? This would be useful in order to see what the attachment is associated with and if it is still in use or if it could be deleted.

Comment: If your product has attachments in it, why do you think your attachments need a product? especially if also companies have attachments? What should product than be? `null`?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question

Comment: What you describe in the UPDATE part sounds like Product and Attachment should be able to exist independent of each other. To achieve that, you should create an entity between them ("Assignment"). Then map this new entity into Produkt/Attachment as @OneToMany.
Like this, you can have a product with attachments, but also re-use attachments for different products.